# How to conditionally bind to attributes in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How to conditionally bind to attributes in vue?

the v-bind directive:

Something like this given below:

```
<img :src=" status = true ? 'open.svg' : 'close.svg'">
```

In angular this is possible. I just wanted to know whether this is possible in vue.

Or is there a  way to write javascript code like the one above in the template itself (ternary ops)?

Comment: You should probably rather have a `computed` property instead of sticking this expression into the template.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
<img :src="status ? 'open.svg' : 'close.svg'" >
```

Or set it as a computed property:

```
<img :src="imgSrc" >
```

```
computed:{
  imgSrc(){
    return (this.status) ? 'open.svg' : 'close.svg'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply try this

```
<img :src="status ? 'open.svg' : 'close.svg'">
```

in your code `status = true` is assignment operator you should use comparison operator like this `status == true`

Comment: as Majed Badawi suggested. the computed property will be always a good option

Answer (score 0):

You can use `status == true` instead of `status = true`.

Just try this.

```js
var vMain = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    status: true,
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <img :src='status == true ? "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/F00/fff" : "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/0F0/fff"'><br />
  <button onclick='vMain.status = ! vMain.status;'>Switch Status</button>
</div>
```